# Spacing between number and short caption in List of Figures in tuftebook

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte-book

I am writing a large book in tuftebook (*TeXShop*) and there is inadequate spacing between the numbering and short captions in the *List of Figures*:

[image]

I have seen several questions and solutions to this problem, such as:

```
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}
```

but all involve changing the overall style and layout of the List of Figures (and other elements in the Table of Contents).  I'd like to retain the tuftebook design and merely increase the spacing between the automatic numbering and the short captions.  Surely, I need merely include a line such as:

```
\setlength{....}{1cm}
```

I just don't know what variable name to include.

(I also have this problem for the basic Table of Contents.)

[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to increase the space allocated to section numbers in the ToC and to figure numbers in the LoF.

[image: b]

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%***************************************  added
\titlecontents{section}% 
    [0em] % distance from left margin
    {\vspace{0\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\Large\rmfamily\itshape} % above ()
    {\hspace*{3em}\contentslabel{3em}} % before w/label 
    {\hspace*{3em}} % before w/o label
    {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad\thecontentspage} % filler + page (leaders and page num)
    [\end{fullwidth}] % after

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tufte@lof@line}{2.0em}{3.0em}{}{} % more width to the number
\makeatother        
%***************************************

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\chapter{Eleven}
\setcounter{section}{10}
\section{Section Eleven}
\section{Section Twelve}

\setcounter{figure}{19}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{XX}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much. (accept)